# Squared-derivative PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-analysis, nonlinear-dynamics

Is there a general theory for equations of the type $ f_y^2 = A(x,y) f_x$? where one first derivative is expressed as a multiple of the other one.

Concretely, I'm interested in the equation

$$ ( x+ y^2 + c) f_x = f_y^2$$

where $f_x = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, 
$f_y = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$.

I tried $f(x,y) = g( z)$ with $z=x+ y^2 + c$ so far, and some variants of this.

Answer (score 2):

I would take a look at the [method of characteristics](https://web.stanford.edu/class/math220a/handouts/firstorder.pdf). This equation is fully nonlinear, so $\S$2.4 would be of interest. If this equation is paired with data to form a Cauchy problem, then the solution is determined at least locally.